# How can I apply textures in Blenders UV Editor

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

so I guess I have a really basic question here. I wanted to apply a texture to my mesh trough the UV Editor. I opened a new Image but here comes the first problem already. 
I can't move/ scale the image.

I need multiple textures on the same spot (Specular, Diffuse, Normal). Once for the front side and once for the back side. 
Do I have to do that in photoshop or is there a way to move images around in the Blender UV Editor? When I am looking for tutorials I only find how they export the UV out and edit it in a seperate software.

Comment: what kind of mesh are you using? A Plane? Use U in the 3D View for unwrapping the mesh and than position it in the UV Editor by using G (grab and move). The UV Map can be used for all textures but you have to use the textures in the material (nodes/setup). Which Render Engine are you using (I would recommend Cycles for things with maps)

Comment: You can't edit an image in the UV editor (unless just painting on it) and it's not supposed to be used in that way. If you want to edit the way how this image is assigned on the mesh edit its UV coordinates in UV editor which will be used for wrapping that image onto the mesh. To change scale of the texture on the mesh either scale the UV map or in the Node editor add Mapping node.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39943/how-to-scale-a-uv-image-texture and https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8697/1245

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using a *Stencil* mapping option. In *UV Editor* set the mode to ***Paint***. Add two textures in a *Texture* panel using the '+' button. Change the brush mapping type to *Stencil*.
[image]

Your texture stencil should appear. Press *Image Aspect* button to get the original picture dimensions. Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> to rotate stencil, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> to change its size and <kbd>RMB</kbd> to pan it. Then paint.
[image]

Click on the texture preview window, choose your second texture (<kbd>Up/Down Arrow</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> or choose it from the textures list) and paint again.
[image]

You can use the same method in a 3D View window. It's very useful for blending/hiding the seams btw.
[image]

Comment: Hey. Thank you a lot. That was somehow what I was looking for. Not perfectly because I wanted to have more Textures at the same place but i guess I will have to use Photoshop for that then. hehe ^^ 

Btw. When I use the stencil mode and I want to apply a character onto a plane. I choose it and scale it the way like I want it. I have everything like you and my mesh is also unwrapped. Now when I paint on it it will be painted multiple times and also on the same objects (which have another material though) .. I will post screenshots asap

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/MNUeE
I hope in the screenshot you can see what i mean. It gets tiled even if i scaled the character into a big one so it takes like 50% of the UV of the model. Also it goes on on the other models which even have another material. (I copied the one i want to add the stencil and made the material a new one). It really is not a duplicate anymore