# Adding condensation effect on a texture

Tags: texturing

How to add condensation effect on a texture?

The way I add condensation effect is to add a texture image (condensation) to object material. However, I don't think we can use this method to add the effect on a texture? As it would be like adding texture on to another texture.

For example the label(coke) in picture below are a texture, how do we add condensation on it?

[image]

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). The easiest way is to use a normal map and connect it into the normal input. That way you don't have to mix/combine anything.

Comment: @JachymMichal Thanks. just tried it, the condensation did appear on the label! However, it has problem on the scaling. The water droplets appeared horizontal stretched, and when I tried to correct it by scaling on the UV map, the Coke label was affected as well (became too thin or too wide). Maybe there is a way to scale individual image rather than to scale the UV unwrap area?

Comment: Hello :). Don't scale the UV map directly, but use the *Mapping node* for each image. [This thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/39943/78972) should help. Also, it's sometimes useful to use a second UV map for the condensation, for better control.

Comment: @JachymMichal hey, that actually worked :)

Comment: And now I am looking for where the Accept Answer button is..... maybe I am new that I dont' have that option?

Comment: There's no way to accept a comment :). I'll post a full answer later, so you can mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a *Normal map* for the condensation.
That way you don't need to mix anything, just plug it into normal input.

[image]

*Example of a normal map.

You can download this one for free from [Poliigon.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9j6m709qmu4bfvz/WaterDropletsMixedBubbled001_NRM16_1K.tif?dl=0)*

[image]

*Connect the normal map like this.

Use different Mapping nodes and perhaps UV maps for better control.*

[image]

Comment: I am using that texture from Poliigon as well, after watching Andrew Price's tutorial :)