# Making dew in blender version 2.79b

Tags: modeling

[image][image][image]how to make dew on drinking cans or similar products using blender 2.79, I've tried it with node texture mapping but the result is more like paint drips on the wall.

Comment: if you want to use texture than you can use this answer probably in 2.79 as well (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/169608/128477), another solution are particle systems